# Simple linked list-C

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

After taking the summer off from C programming, I'm back in the thick of it for classes and am trying to catch up, particularly in pointers.

The current assignment has us converting a program from an array structure to a simple linked list.  In order to refresh my memory, I've tried implementing it in a standalone program, but am running into trouble.

My code:

```
struct node{
  int val;
  struct node *next;
};

typedef struct node *item;

item newNode(void); //function prototype

void main(){
    item *cur, *itemList;
    int i;

    itemList=NULL;

    for (i=0; i<=10; i++){
        cur= newNode();
        cur->val=i;
        cur->next= itemList;

    }
}

item newNode(void) {
    item box;  /* the new object to return */

    box = (item) malloc (sizeof (struct node));

    if (box == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR: emalloc failed for new Box\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    /* initialize fields */
    box->val=0;

    return box;

}
```

The first error message is coming at `cur= newBox()` and is stating that an assigment from an incompatible pointer type is being made.  I'm not sure why, since cur is a pointer to a node, and box is a structure.  Where does the incompatible pointer come from?

Comment: you call the function `newBox`, but only declare `newNode`, perhaps a typo in the call? Keep in mind, that C has the "implicit int" rule where undefined functions are assumed to have the prototype `int func()`

Comment: It was a typo in my post, not the code.  I edited as such

Comment: In general, I've found typedef to be overused (as is the case here where it contributed to your error). Don't use it unless you can very clearly explain to your cat why you used it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first problem is that your doing `item *cur, *itemList;` which is a `node**`. Change that to `item cur, itemList;` to get `node*`'s; you don't need a pointer to a pointer to a `node`, just a pointer to a `node`.

Another problem is that you're setting all the `next` pointers of your nodes to `itemList` without setting `itemList` to `cur` at the end of each loop iteration (which will make `itemList` point to the beginning of the list at the end of the loop).

Answer (score 3):

You need a pointer

It is clearer if your typedef is like this:

```
typedef struct node item;
```

then:

```
item *newNode(void) {
    item *box;  /* the new object to return */

    box = (item) malloc (sizeof (struct node));

    if (box == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR: emalloc failed for new Box\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    /* initialize fields */
    box->val=0;

    return box;

}
```

Also you call the function newNode and newBox in different places.

You also need to reset the head pointer:

```
for (i=0; i<=10; i++){
    cur= newBox();
    cur->val=i;
    cur->next= itemList;
    itemList = cur;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In main you are using `item*` which is `node**`. Just remove the `*` in the declaration list in main.

Answer (score 0):

`cur` is of type `item*`, pointer to item. But the return type of `newNode(void)` is `item`. They both are not type compatible.