# preventing memory reuse upon exiting scope in c

Tags: c, memory

I'm trying to create a linked list from input in c as follows:

```
int s;
scanf("%d", &s);
struct Node n = {0, NULL};
struct Node *prev = &n;
for (int i = 0; i < s; ++i)
{
    struct Node cur = {0, NULL};
    scanf((i<s-1)?"%d,":"%d", &cur.data);

    //printf("%d\n", &cur);

    prev->next = &cur;
    prev = &cur;
}
n = *(n.next);
```

However, it seems the memory for cur is re-used when the loop proceeds to the next iteration. As a result, the list contains a single self-referential node.

Is there a way to prevent the memory from being re-used like this?

I know I could use malloc, and allocate all the memory before the loop, but this requires knowledge of how many elements are in the linked list, and I'm hoping to remove the initial request for size.

Comment: Please read up about `malloc`, heaps etc

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314581/simple-linked-list-c might be a starter

Comment: > I know I could use malloc, and allocate all the memory before the loop < `malloc` is used specifically to allocate memory when initial amount of memory is not known. and you can call it within loop body

Comment: You don't have to know how many elements are in the list, that's why it's called **dynamic** memory allocation, it's done at runtime. Just change the `cur` allocation with `struct Node *cur = malloc(sizeof *cur);`. Ofc, pay attention to free all that allocated memory at the end of your program or when you're done with the list.

Comment: It's not just that the memory is being "reused", it's that you're invoking *undefined behavior" by keeping a pointer to a local variable after the function has returned.

Comment: @fanton allocating memory within the loop hadn't occured to me, what I was talking about was `struct Node *n = malloc(s*sizeof(struct Node))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to control lifetime of a variable independently of its scope in C is allocating it inthe dynamic store. You cannot prevent a reuse of an automatic variable.

In your case it means simply using

```
struct Node *curv=malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
scanf((i<s-1)?"%d,":"%d", &cur->data);
prev->next = cur;
prev = cur;
```

The great thing about this approach is that you do *not* need to know how many element you are going to need. You allocate them one at a time, and stop when you need to stop. Of course, this flexibility comes at the price of allocating an additional pointer element.